# MongoDB see all data inside model

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongoDB and I am trying to comprehend how can we see data inside a model in my DB

So, I did something like this first (In terminal)

```
use football
```

which returned something like this

```
switched to db football
```

then I did

```
show collections
```

which showed me the model I created inside it using mongoose with Node.js,

```
players
```

Now, How can I see/view the data I added inside my players? in Terminal itself? Also any GUI application for using Mongoose locally?

Comment: db.players.find(); or for a better view db.players.find().pretty();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

```
db.players.find()
```

Here "players" is NOT your model, it's a collection of documents inside the database. The very term of "model" refers to something inside your application, not the database.

Answer (score 1):

For GUI, check out [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/).
Its free as well